# In Foundry, is it possible to extract the original file names from a concatenated import?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I need to import billions of very small image files into Foundry. I understand Foundry won't handle that amount of files very well, so best practice would be to concatenate them and make the import incremental.

However, I need to be able to get the raw files and their names to be able to process them in my pipeline. How can I get the original files back from the concatenated file?

Comment: Would it be a good idea to edit the title to be clear that this question is about binary/image files, as for unnconcatenated  text files there are different (& better) schema based solutions?

Comment: Added a question on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695797/can-i-get-the-file-names-for-synced-text-files-in-my-pipeline-in-foundry/70695798

Answer (score 0):

The original file names, sizes, and modified dates are included in the transaction metadata:

[image]

Assuming you'll need data across multiple transactions, you likely want to do this as incrementally as possible.