# Can I get the file names for synced text files in my pipeline in Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I have a bunch of text files that are synced from my raw system, I want an easy way to use the file names (in addition to the contents of the files) downstream in Foundry transforms.

I know this is possible using raw file access, but that seems complicated, I just want the file names next to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're immediately going into code repos or code workbooks, then you can use the [input_file_name()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html) function (see [proggeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7594271/proggeo)'s answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70696089/3507465)).  This is likely easier and simpler than the below, but won't work if you're going to do something else with the data.

**Schema Method**

If you open your dataset, then go to Details -> Schema, you can edit the schema to add a file path column, for each row this will have the value of the path of the file that the row comes from.

The key part is the `_filePath` member of `fieldSchemaList` and `"addFilePath": true` under `customMetadata`. The first is a special column that `TextDataFrameReader` populates with the file path, the second tells the reader to populate that column.  The other column in the example below (`content`) just contains everything in each file.

For more details see the `Metadata` section in the `Foundry core backend` in platform documentation.  This is also possible for csv's and more structured data with different Reader classes.

**Full schema example**

```
{
"fieldSchemaList": [
    {
        "type": "STRING",
        "name": "content",
        "nullable": null,
        "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
        "customMetadata": {},
        "arraySubtype": null,
        "precision": null,
        "scale": null,
        "mapKeyType": null,
        "mapValueType": null,
        "subSchemas": null
    },
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "_filePath",
      "nullable": null,
      "userDefinedTypeClass": null,
      "customMetadata": {},
      "arraySubtype": null,
      "precision": null,
      "scale": null,
      "mapKeyType": null,
      "mapValueType": null,
      "subSchemas": null
    }
],
"dataFrameReaderClass": "com.palantir.foundry.spark.input.TextDataFrameReader",
"customMetadata": {
    "textParserParams": {
      "parser": "SINGLE_COLUMN_PARSER",
      "nullValues": null,
      "nullValuesPerColumn": null,
      "charsetName": "UTF-8",
      "addFilePath": true,
      "addByteOffset": false,
      "addImportedAt": false
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from ollie299792458 will work only if dataFrameReaderClass is com.palantir.foundry.spark.input.TextDataFrameReader.

Alternatively you can get a file name when reading the dataset in Code Repositories or Workbooks using Spark [input_file_name](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html) function:

```
Creates a string column for the file name of the current Spark task.
```